Routing through a throughole testpoint
I am in the layout phase of designing a PCB, I've got a testpoint on the 5V supply, which then gets routed further.
Is it bad practice to lay it out like this, if so what are the disadvantages.


5V supply is by no means a critical signal so I don't see why it wouldn't be a problem. Why can't you add a separate via for it though? It costs literally nothing.

Hello and welcome.  Just for reference, how wide are those tracks, eg C1.1 to TP7?

Hi and welcome.
One reason could be that you make a hole in all layers underneath, which would be unnecessary.

I think the question needs further info, why do you need a through hole test point and route through it to begin with? Do you want to be able to measure 5V from both sides, solder a pinheader to the hole, split the 5V to both sides of board for routing, or something else? It's one more hole to drill, makes a hole to all layers in the PCB, so it depends what you value and what you want to avoid, or if the effect is insignificant. For example, why is the 5V not a copper plane but narrow track?

It is not a via, it's a testpoint for a keystone testpoint connector, I find those easy to probe.

I didn't think about making it a plane, that is a good suggestion. The current trackwidth for the power traces are .4 mm

First of all, it depends heavy on the current which is flowing through this trace. Also keep in mind that inrush currents, which are bigger than the normal current, may occour. If you have the space, which you seem to have, I would suggest thicker traces.
If you want to design for hobby use, it may work. But it is better practice to not route through vias. Routing through testpoints is fine, as long as they are on the same layer.

If you want to have a via, I would recommend routing the trace near it and make a little breakout trace to it. This way you keep the current path clear of obstacles.
